# how to get Grid looks like CRM Grids?

Tags: css, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

In a Html web resource I am using a table. Is it possible to get a grid with same looks like CRM 2011 grids.I have tried css from SDK. Result was not satisfactory.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The grid in CRM is just a composite of different HTML controls, so yes, it's possible. In fact, that's the only way.

Now, I understand that you're looking for a quick way to apply a CSS file and to make it work. I tried that once but didn't really get that to work (maybe because it was my first month with CRM). I suspect that there are a lot of different CSS files that need to cooperate.

What we did was basically a "close enough" appearance and we told the customer that the difference in what it looked like was due to a "more improved" approach. They accepted it.

Comment: Rather than being "less than truthful" I would have told them the cost to get it exact doesn't justify the benefit.  Unless they're fine with you spending a week tweaking the css to get it to look "exact".  (And then when they upgrade to the next version of CRM, they get to pay that cost, all over again)

Answer (score 0):

Styling your own Html to match is pretty tricky and that's before you even consider the options within CRM to change the colour scheme for pure aesthetics or accessibility (high contrast).

Having said this I [blogged](http://frozenorange.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/custom-web-pages-with-crm-2011-look-and-feel-using-knockout-js/) about creating a custom dialog to match the default battleship grey style.  It may provide helpful as I outline all the stylesheets involved.